# Refactor jquery to pass jquery-lint

Tags: jquery, jquery-lint

I have the following code in an html page

```
jQuery("input[name='newstate']").change(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).attr("checked")) {
        jQuery('input[name="new-state-name"]').show();
    } else {
        jQuery('input[name="new-state-name"]').hide();
    }
});
```

But jquery lint gives following message.

> You should only use the same selector more than once when you know the returned collection will be different. For example, if you've added more elements to the page that may comply with the selector

How do I modify my code to remove this message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide) method accepts a Boolean for `showOrHide`:

```
jQuery("input[name='newstate']").change(function(){
    // You can use this.checked instead of jQuery(this).attr("checked");
    jQuery('input[name="new-state-name"]').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

This way you'll *know* that the `new-state-name` input's display state *always* matches the `newstate` input (i.e., it will show when checked, unregarding it's previous state). What I mean is, using `toggle()` without `showOrHide` you can risk that the `newstate` state and `new-state-name` display state runs out of sync if e.g. the `new-state-name` input's display state is manipulated from outside the `newstate` `change()` handler.

---

Of course you could also just assign the result set to a temporary variable in order to perform the selector only once:

```
jQuery("input[name='newstate']").change(function(){
    var newStateInput = jQuery('input[name="new-state-name"]');
    if(this.checked) {
        newStateInput.show();
        // ... more here
    } else {
        newStateInput.hide();
        // ... and/or here
    }
});
```

if you intend to do more than show/hide.

---

**EDIT**
Oops, unfortunate typo. `show()` should be `toggle()` in first solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("input[name='newstate']").change(function(){
      jQuery('input[name="new-state-name"]').toggle();
});
```